# How to create a macro that generates an array of constructors known dynamically by name in Haxe?

Tags: macros, haxe

*I'm targeting **javascript**.*

I have a macro that runs on **Context.onGenerate()** that saves a subset of fully qualified type names to a file. Then, another build macro (which would run on the next buid) reads the list of type names from the file in order to create add a static field to a class which is supposed to hold those types (constructors) in the array.

The field which I want to generate from the second macro would be something like this:

```
public static _entities:Array<Class<entities.Entity>> = [
    entities.Foo,
    entities.Bar,
    ...
];
```

Which would generate the following javascript

```
MyClass._entities = [ entities_Foo, entities_Bar, ... ];
```

Now I've tried writing the field manually to make sure everything generates properly--it does. However I can't figure out the right way to write the macro, I get stuck on adding a identifier constant as the value of the array expression, which always ends up in a **"Unknown identifier"** error:

```
var id = { expr: EConst( CIdent( "entities.Foo" ) ), 
           pos: Context.currentPos() };

var ex  = EArrayDecl([ id ]);

fields.push( {
    name    : "_entities",
    access  : [Access.APublic, Access.AStatic ],
    pos     : Context.currentPos(),
    kind    : FVar( 
                macro:Array<Class<entities.Entity>>,

                // I've tried writing it without reification: (see above vars)
                { expr: ex, pos:Context.currentPos() }

                // Or w/ reification:
                macro $a{[ $i{ "entities.Foo" } ]}
              )
});
```

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible with macros? If so could direct me in the steps to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to output it as a single identifier while it's in fact a dot-path, which should be represented as a chain of `EField`s to a first `EIdent`. Luckily, Haxe has a handy "path" [reification](http://haxe.org/manual/macro-reification-expression.html) right for that: try `$p{path.split(".")}` (where `path` is your `"entities.Foo"` string).

Comment: Well this one is much more simpler than the solution I found. And it worked perfectly. Thanks for yet another handy tip, nadako.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more digging on the API reference I figured out how to do it. It turns out I needed **TypedExpr** instead of just an identifier constant.

A **TTypeExpr** with a **ModuleType** of **TClassDecl** would yield the correct result.
So my example code above becomes:

```
static function getTypeRef( name:String ):Ref<ClassType>
{
    var type = Context.getType( name );

    switch( type )
    {
        default: return Context.error( "Expected a ClassType", Context.currentPos() );
        case TInst( cr, _ ):
            return cr;
    }
}


static function getTypes()
{
    // Obtain ClassType by identifier
    var fooCls = getTypeRef( "entities.Foo" );

    // Get a TypedExpr for the ClassType
    var typedExpr:TypedExpr = {
        expr : TTypeExpr( TClassDecl( fooCls ) ),
        t    : TInst( fooCls, [] ),
        pos  : Context.currentPos()
    };

    // Convert to Expr
    var expr:Expr = Context.getTypedExpr( typedExpr );

    var fields = Context.getBuildFields();

    fields.push( {
        name    : "_entities",
        access  : [Access.APublic, Access.AStatic ],
        pos     : Context.currentPos(),
        kind    : FVar( 
                    macro:Array<Class<entities.Entity>>,
                    macro $a{[ ${expr} ]}   // <- Now it works here
                  )
    });

    return fields;
}
```